# how to do url rewriting for dynamically generated links

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url

I have created a small link which is dynamically generated. When i click on that link which will create a URL like this

```
http://localhost/store/user.php?id=12
```

if i give this url

```
http://localhost/store/user/12
```

which will produce the same out put which i want to see

What i want to do is that if i click on dynamically generated link which should produce

```
 http://localhost/store/user/12
```

this url instead of this

```
http://localhost/store/user.php?id=12
```

how can i do this

.httaccess file is this

```
# Enable Rewriting
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite user URLs
#   Input:  user/NAME/
#   Output: user.php?id=NAME
RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/?$ user.php?id=$1
```

Comment: I think you have the basic misunderstanding of thinking this .htaccess code will automatically transform your links. In fact it won't. What the .htaccess code does, more precisely the mod_rewrite module code, is to reinterpret certain patterns in the URL -what we like calling "pretty URLs"- It processes this pretty URLs and rewrite them internally. The thing is, you have to force your links somehow to be in that form. Be it manually or through some programming.

Comment: my intention is this i want to produce a link like this  http://localhost/store/user/12 insted of this http://localhost/store/user.php?id=12 when user clicks on a link which is dynamicalley generated how can i achieve this?.@MarkSkayff

Comment: You say the links are dynamically generated. This means something is generating them. You must be able to modify that something, script code probably, and make it generate the new kind of links. That part doesn't have to do with the .htaccess. You must first tweak how the links are generated.

Comment: @MarkSkayff thank you mark i have misunderstood url redirection thank you tanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^store/user/(\w+)/?$ store/user.php?id=$1
```

Comment: If i click on  user link on index page it is still producing the url http://localhost/store/user.php?id=12